# How to create dynamic query for inner join on same table?

Tags: database

I want a dynamic query to do inner join on same table.

My query is:

```
SELECT t1.table1 FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name"
```

I want to join table1 and table2 based on id and name present in table2.

What is the equivalent dynamic query in Drupal for this?
How this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = db_select('table1','t1');
$query->join('table2','t2','t1.id1=t2.id2');
$query->fields('t1', array('some fields'))
      ->fields('t2', array('some fields'));
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```

Then you can do print_r stuff into $result like

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($result);echo "</pre>";
```

If you have devel module installed and enabled, then you can also use:-

```
dsm($result);
```

This will give the whole result in form of array.
If you need in form of object, then you need to modify few lines of code like this:-

```
$data = $result->execute();
while($result = $data->fetchObject()){
  //Do your related stuff
}
```

I think it will help a lot. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @DeepakKumar. I want to join with name also. how to do the join with both of id and name in dynamic query?

Comment: Please clear the question, I dont understand the dynamic query and both of id and name?
I have some kind of foreign key present in both table
right?
then u need to apply join on it, that's it :)

Comment: I want something like this.
$query = db_select('table1','t1');
$query->join('table2','t2','t1.id1=t2.id2');
$query->join('table2', 't2, 't1.name=t2.name'); is it possible to join like this?

Comment: @GanesanGopal yes, but every `alias` must be unique. You cannot have two `t2` like do you now. `db_select('table1', 't1'); $query->join('table2', 't2', '%alias.id2= t1.id1'); $query->join('table2', 't3', 't1.name=t2.name');`

Comment: @tenken yes every alias must be unique. I am referring the name field which is present in table2. So I think this query is right. Can u confirm?

Comment: you can add any number of conditions to a `JOIN` statement -- as long as they make sense to your database structure you're fine.

Comment: k. thanks for your info @tenken. what is that %alias meant in 4th comment?

Comment: `JOIN`s return a join expression, not a `SelectQuery`. You cannot chain Joins together. In `$query->join('table2', 't2', '%alias.id2 = t1.id1');` the placeholder `%alias` is converted by Drupal to `t2` (the table alias you define for the join). If you have many similar joins -- this lets you re-use a string join statement.